# FortiVPN Route Add Failure

Tags: vpn, route, kubuntu

I am running `Kubuntu 23.04` with the latest public version of FortiClient (`7.0.7.0246`) which can be obtained via the website, [here](https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads). I have configured the product to connect to my IP VPN, which worked fine on Ubuntu, but on this machine I get an error wherein it won't connect.

I believe the issue is surrounding some form of permission guard on Kubuntu that might not be present on Ubuntu (or, some missing dependency). As I do not have the route table handy, it is not possible for me to run an `ifup` script to inject the routes myself.

```
20230703 08:08:05.319 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:364 Restore DNS config
20230703 08:08:05.319 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:421 Device name: eno2
20230703 08:08:05.319 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:422 Connection name: LAN
20230703 08:08:05.319 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:423 Ignor auto DNS: no
20230703 08:08:05.319 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:424 DNS list: 
20230703 08:08:05.319 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:425 DNS search domain list: 
20230703 08:08:05.319 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:426 VPN device name: vpn00d1ca2667
20230703 08:08:05.485 [sslvpn:DEBG] route:159 begin cleanup linux...
20230703 08:08:05.485 [sslvpn:DEBG] route:161 clean up route...
20230703 08:08:05.485 [sslvpn:DEBG] main:1697 exception: Config routing table failed
20230703 08:08:05.626 [sslvpn:INFO] main:1651 Init
20230703 08:08:05.626 [sslvpn:INFO] main:1707 VPN is running in restore DNS mode
20230703 08:08:05.627 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:364 Restore DNS config
20230703 08:08:05.627 [sslvpn:DEBG] dns:416 No backup file was found. Skip.
```

As for permissions, I have attempted to run the `forticlientvpn` application (within `/opt/forticlient`) as `sudo` and as `root`, but it will not start with administrative functions. I cannot easily replicate this using `openfortivpn` without some hacks to [support SSO and SAML](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn/issues/867), so unsure if this is limited to this application as an issue.

If I run the application via the CLI ( `/opt/forticlient/fortivpn connect $PROFILE`) I am returned with this message:

> Notification: Login failed: Insufficient credential(s). Please check the password, client certificate, etc.
> DONE.

In the handshake, I have to approve a certificate which is untrusted; again, I don't recall this on Ubuntu. To further test, I have also enforced the following on the configuration of `$Profile`:

> Remote Gateway [current=sso-vpn.linux.obscurefqdn.com.au:9825]:
> Authentication (1.prompt / 2.save / 3.disable) [current=disable]: 1
> Client Certificate (.p12 file URL) (or type 'remove' to unset) [current=]:
> Do not Warn Invalid Server Certificate (y/n) [current=n]: y

I know the profile and credentials are sufficient, as I've connected on my MacBook and Windows this morning to validate; and this worked ~8 hours ago when I had Ubuntu (and not Kubuntu) installed; but I bricked that OS ;)

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Attempted to configure via the Network Options, and was presented with needing to install [this module](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-fortisslvpn) which I could only find via Synaptics. Unfortunately, doesn't look like the GUI supports SSO, so this hasn't assisted; nor did it help with the inital connection.

Comment: Running FortiClient 7.0.8.0292 which was available via the Synaptics Store has worked; although I believe this is the *paid* version on a trial, will look into it further.